# postMessage to parent, parent code not running

Tags: javascript

I have seen loads of examples and I can't see where i'm going wrong. But my event listener isn't running at all within the parent. Event if I post a message manually within the iframe console scope.

iframe:

```js
$(".open").click(function() {
        window.parent.postMessage('navigated', '*', []);
```

parent:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    document.querySelectorAll('iframe[src*="forms.localhost"]').forEach(iframe => {
        iframe.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
            console.log('event');
        });
    });
```

I have checked and the querySelector is finding my iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent window should listen for messages on the parent window, not on the `iframe` elements. A single handler will receive messages from all of the iframes; you can differentiate them by the `origin` on the message.

Comment: Thanks, all the examples I looked at showed the event listener on the iframe! lol

Comment: @MartynBall - Yikes! :-)

Comment: Is there a way to get the iframe element from the `message`? I need to basically find out the position of the iframe when that message is posted.

Comment: @MartynBall - I'm sorry to say I've never tried to do that. One way that comes to mind, though, is to use the `origin` of the message and use a CSS selector on the `iframe`'s `src` attribute...? Ugh, but `origin` probably only includes the origin information, not the full URL. :-| Second thought: You could pass some kind of synthetic ID to the iframe as a query parameter that it could include in the data of the message and use that same ID as a `data-id` attribute on the `iframe` element.